# Getting request header sent by Flash

Tags: flash, firefox-addon, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, greasemonkey

I am not sure if this is even possible but I guess it doesn't hurt to ask.

I have a script, either through Greasemonkey or as a Chrome extension, on a page that contains a Flash application. That flash application sends out POST requests e.g. `www.example.com/api/request.json?var=something`.

Is it possible for the script running on that same page to capture the request header sent by the Flash code? Kind of like Tamper Data, Fiddler and the like do.

Thanks very much in advance even if the answer ends up being no :)

EDIT: Just a little more info that might help. I don't need to redirect or alter the request coming from the Flash application. I just to be able to read in the header and save that information in a variable in the user script / extension that is running on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to capture and re-route or edit that application request you can simply make an entry into your hosts file (if on windows) and run a local web server like [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) to handle the request on your machine. This is essentially completely hijacking requests to that server and you can do whatever you want with it. See [this](http://support.modwest.com/content/8/52/en/how-do-i-change-my-hosts-file-or-how-can-i-see-my-domain-before-dns-changes-propagate.html) for details on how to add entries to your hosts file.

Also if you need to edit your hosts entries on another system like linux or mac, just google the same concept except add your os name next to the search. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I really need to do this from within a user script or extension. I can do it manually using a http sniffer but ideally I would like to intercept the header sent from the Flash application from a user script / extension that is on the same page.

I don't need to redirect it or alter it in any way. I just need to update information in the user script / extension whenever the header information changes.

Thanks for your post though. It will help me in testing a few other things out :)

Answer (score 0):

With GreaseMoneky, no.

As they state [in their FAQ](http://wiki.greasespot.net/FAQ#What_does_Greasemonkey_do.3F):

> Greasemonkey lets you add JavaScript code (called "user scripts") to any web page, which will run when its HTML code has loaded. [...] User scripts work more or less like bookmarklets automatically invoked for any URLs matching one or more glob patterns.

They won't be able to intercept what happens "live" as you would do with FireBug or WireShark.

They execute code when the DOM is ready and then die.

Update:

If you need to do this only to find which requests are fired, and not to intercept and/or act upon them, you can use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) (if you use Firefox) or Chrome's integrated development tools (press F12).

Comment: I was afraid this would be the answer. I would prefer to be able to intercept so I can perform actions based on header changes. It's not the end of the world if I can't. Would of just made my life easier :)

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @runey71: Then the easiest option (if it's not a recurring thing) is using some sort of proxy like [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/), [Polipo](http://www.pps.jussieu.fr/~jch/software/polipo/) or [TinyProxy](https://banu.com/tinyproxy/).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'm check them out now.

Comment: I checked out the proxy options. It's not really what I'm after but then again I think what I'm after is not possible. Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to capture HTTP POST request headers sent from Flash using [`chrome.experimental.webRequest`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/experimental.webRequest.html) extension API, but if by headers you mean the actual form data being sent, then it is not part of the headers (and cannot be captured using extension API afaik).

```
chrome.experimental.webRequest.onRequestSent.addListener(function(details) {
    console.log("Headers:", details);
}, null,  ["requestLine", "requestHeaders"]);
```

Comment: I mean actual header information like Accept and Referer etc. Thank you for your answer I will have a closer look at `chrome.experimental.webRequest`

Comment: Finally got around to have a closer look at `chrome.experimental.webRequest`

Unfortunately I got an error chrome.experimental.webRequest is not supported in content scripts

So it seems like it is not permitted to be used in extensions.

Comment: @runey71 You can't use any Chrome API in content scripts (well, most of it), you need to call it from a background page.